# Woocomerce: get Custom Field (ACF) in template file

Tags: woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I create a custom field using the Advanced Custom Field (ACF) plugin: `mycustomfield`

This custom field is attached to **Product pages**

In a template view page I need to print the value of the custom field for a given Product. I have the Product Page ID in: $product_id

`echo $product_id; // this print the correct product page id`

I tried these two lines of code, but none of them worked:

`echo $my_custom_field = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'mycustomfield', true ); // print nothing`

`echo $my_custom_field = get_field('mycustomfield', $product_id); // print nothing`

Comment: Have you checked the WordPress debug log? If there is an issue I can help you asap. But I need some logs for this because normally the first line of code should work. You can find the debug.log in your wp-content folder. If there is no debug log, you need to enable it (https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and reload the page -> check the logs and post it here.